# How to insert text column of single row based on value of other column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by, case

I want to insert a text result of sigal row depending upon the value of specific parameter.

For eg.

Table1

```
Id | status
____________
23 | complete
24 | going on
34 | failed
56 | complete
```

Now in Table1 if any one or more entry is with status 'failed' then my query result should be:

```
Result | tableName
___________________
Failed | Table1
```

If any one or more entry is with status 'going on' and no row has status 'failed' then my query result should be:

```
Result | tableName
___________________
Going on | Table1
```

At the end, if all values are 'complete' in status column then result should be:

```
Result | tableName
___________________
Complete | Table1
```

In conclusion, result of query is based on 'status' column and priority is:

```
1. Failed
2. Going on
3. Complete
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want conditional aggregation:

```
select
    case
        when count(*) filter(where status = 'failed')   > 0 then 'failed'
        when count(*) filter(where status = 'going on') > 0 then 'going on'
        when count(*)                                   > 0  then 'complete'
    end result
from mytable
```

You could also do this with a conditional sort and a row-limiting clause, which might be more efficient:

```
select status
from mytable
order by 
    status = 'failed'   desc,
    status = 'going on' desc,
    status = 'complete' desc
limit 1
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f9af3de3d7c5ad50c7547ce6823ecd43)**